# Script to write interactive user input and execute command in remote server

Tags: linux, scripting

I am looking to write a script which does following

1. List item
2. As I run it, it should ask for sever entry(linux or AIX)
3. Once it is provided, I should be able to login into it with sudo access
4. Then it should run command from particular location and display the output.

I have been looking for this entire day on this site, but could not find the satisfactory answer.

Hope to get good response on this.

Thanks 
Abhi

Comment: you need an expect-like tool, such as expectJ, expect4j, etc

Comment: or invoke commands via ssh

Comment: @julumme expectJ provides integration with Jsch

Comment: or even expect itself (sorry, I was focusing on java tools)

Comment: I am Using below format
#! /bin/sh
#_EPLF=/ngs/lpp/autor11p/SysytemAgent/$_MNA/cybAgent -v
_RPT=`echo "/tmp/"$_YDT"-stat.rpt"`
_EPL=`echo $_EPLF$_YDT`
_STA=`echo "/tmp/"$_YDT"-mac-rpt.sta"`


clear
echo "Enter Machine Name: \c"

read _MNA
clear


        if [ -z "$_MNA" ] 
        then
        echo No MACHINE Name
        else
echo "**************** Machine Defenition Details ****************"
echo ==============================================================
./ngs/lpp/autor11p/SysytemAgent/$_MNA/cybAgent -v
echo ""
echo ""
fi

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  As Leo pointed out, you could use Tcl/expect.  This tool allows you to emulate a user and interact with programs as if you were at the keyboard.  You can provide passwords to login clients and so forth.  It's a bit involved and sometimes not so reliable.  If you're using ssh to log in, it might be easier depending on your skills just to use your favorite shell script and use pre-exchanged keys for logging in.  If you do an `ls ~/.ssh` in the directory of the system you're logging in from (running the script), you may see a file called `id_rsa.pub` or similar.  If not, you can use `ssh-keygen` to create one.  Then create or edit the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the machine you're logging into.  Append the contents of this file (`id_rsa.pub`) to `authorized_keys`.  This should allow you to log into that user from the other machine without a password (note: This could be a security risk!).  Then, you can use the command `ssh user@dest -C remote_command` to execute your command, obviating the need for `expect`.